# "that is what is going on here" - awkward or not?

Tags: sentence-construction

> **That is what is going on here.**

This sentence seems weird to me, as there is double "is", plus "what" and "that".

I tried to google the whole phrase and got zero results.

What I want to say is: "that" (the actual issue) is what is going on here (actually happening, not what we led to believe).

Is the sentence okay?

Comment: Try contracting *that* and *is*, and *what* and *is*, because they're not that common in their expanded forms.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't quite understand your answer.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_(grammar)#English

Comment: I got that part now. Thank you. Are the sentence structure and word choice correct?

Comment: Yeah. Just search for it on Google News and you'll find plenty of examples in English-language newspapers in the U.S., for example. We don't do proofreading here, however.

Comment: thank you. I was not sure about double "is"

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is perfectly fine. There is no problem with the repetition of **is**. The repetition is useful for effect, for example if you are using this sentence to summarise a long explanation which ought to have been obvious.

As indicated in the comments, if you feel that the repetition is too formal, one of the instances can be contracted :

> That's what is going on here.
>   *That* is what's going on here.

The second version is used when you wish to lay stress on *that*, because *that's* weakens the emphasis.